# How should we change the function to apply Masters theorem

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I have a running time complexity of a function as below:

T(n)=$\frac{3}{5}$T($\frac{3n}{5}$)+$\frac{c}{n}$ for n>1

I see that we cannot apply Masters theorem directly as it is not in the desired form (a=$\frac{3}{5}$ which is less than 1). Is there any way to apply Masters theorem or what are the methods I can use to find the tight bound of the function. I tried using induction but couldn't find a proper series.

Comment: A bit of googling finds the [Akra–Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), which only requires $a \gt 0$. Might be worth a look.

Comment: Yes, got it. Akra-Bazzi method solved this. Thank you.